# How to delete post which is converted to a comment?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

I add answer to question on [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) but someone convert my answer to comment and the after I realize my answer was incorrect and I want to delete it but it is not posible now. So, is there solution how to completely remove my "deleted" answer? Thank you.

[image: My deleted answer]

Answer (score 7):

The answer is already deleted - hence the pink background. Deleted posts aren't linked to from your profile, but if you browse to a question you will always see your deleted answer and if you have a link you'll always be able to view your deleted questions.

Only users with over 10k (2k on beta sites) reputation and moderators can see deleted answers so most people won't see your answer.

If you want to delete the comment go to the question, find your comment - it will still have your name next to it - and click on the "x".

If you want the content to be invisible to all users - then that's a little harder (if not effectively impossible) to achieve. In the first instance you can still edit the deleted answer and replace the incorrect text with something else. However, that will probably make people **more** interested in the edit history of the post and hence more likely to look at the revision history and see what you edited out. The Community Managers *can* delete post revisions from the database but this is only done when details such as user names and passwords or API keys were included in the first version of the post. In this case a request for revision deletion would be refused.

Comment: I already remove it. But I am little bit confused when I still se my answer. Thank you for your respond.

Comment: And reason why I send my answer as 'Answer' is that I can't comment post as new contributor. It's illogical, I can't send comments but my answer is transferred to comment.